# Object of class Calculator could not be converted to string

Tags: php, poo

soy novato en el tema de la POO, debo crear una clase que contenga un metodo de suma, recibe los valores por parametro.

He programado esto pero evidentemente no funciona, ¿que hago mal?

Muchas gracias

```
<?php

class Calculator{

   public $resultado;

    function sumar ($a, $b){
    
        return ($a + $b);
    }
}

$resultado = new Calculator;
$resultado->sumar( 27,2); 

echo $resultado;
?>
```

Comment: Cuando decis evidentemente no funciona... no nos decis nada.. que quiere decir? tira un error? no hace lo que tiene que hacer? tira un resultado erroneo? yo supongo, que tu problema es que no estas mostrando el retorno de la funcion sumar.. estas mostrando la clase resultado... que pasaba si el echo lo ponias en la instruccion anterior?

Comment: No imprimas al objeto instanciado, de hecho ese código te funcionará si mueves el `echo` a la línea donde accedes al método `sumar`, por cierto era mas fácil desde el inicio colocar que el error dice: **Object of class Calculator could not be converted to string**

Comment: Nada es evidente. No funciona debe comentarse como "encuentro el error XYZ" y poner en tu pregunta la traza de error.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @Alfabravo en siguientes publicaciones lo hare como comentas

Answer (score 3):

Estás tratando de hacer un `echo` a la clase entera. Deberías asignar el resultado a una nueva variable o hacer el `echo` directamente al método, ya que tiene un return:

```
$salida = $resultado->sumar(27,2); 
echo $salida;
```

o

```
echo $resultado->sumar(27,2);
```

Otra opción, si quieres hacer uso de la propiedad pública que has creado sería que el método de suma en lugar de devolver el resultado lo asigne a esa propiedad y luego accedas a ella:

```
class Calculator{

   public $resultado;

    function sumar ($a, $b){
        $this->resultado = $a + $b;
    }
}

$calculator = new Calculator;
$calculator->sumar(27,2);

echo $calculator->resultado;
```

Answer (score 3):

Estás tratando de imprimir la clase, la asignas en `new Calculator`, al hacer `$resultado->suma` la variable no se reasigna, ese `public $resultado` no es necesario ya que no lo usas en ninguna parte de la clase ni se obtiene fuera de esta

```
class Calculator{
    public function sumar ($a, $b){
        return ($a + $b);
    }
}

$calc = new Calculator();
$resultado = $calc->sumar(27,2); 

echo $resultado;
```

Answer (score 1):

tu errror se da porque intentas imprimir la instancia de clase

```
class Calculator{

   public $resultado;

    public function sumar ($a, $b){
    
        return ($a + $b);
    }
}

// se crea una instancia de la clase y se asigna a $calculadora
$calculadora = new Calculator;
// de la instancia $calculadora se utiliza su metodo sumar
// se asigna el resultado a $resultado
$resultado=$calculadora->sumar( 27,2); 

// se imprime el valor retornado
echo $resultado;
```